# Regex not extracting image url from html tag

Tags: java, regex

My regular expression is

```
<source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="70px" data-srcset="(.*?)"/>
```

The text I'm testing my regex with is

```
<source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="70px" data-srcset="https://static2.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/52f81afc8b39c.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=70&amp;h=70 70w"/>
```

It does not detect a URL inside the data-srcset attribute.

My code is

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    private static final String IMG_PREFIX =
            "<source media=\"(min-width: 0px)\" sizes=\"70px\" data-srcset=\"";
    private static final String IMG_SUFFIX = "\"/>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "<source media=\"(min-width: 0px)\" sizes=\"70px\" data-srcset=\"https://static1.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Michael-Bloomberg.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=70&amp;h=70 70w\"/>";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(IMG_PREFIX + "(.*?)" + IMG_SUFFIX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        System.out.println(matcher.find());

    }
}
```

Edit: the production code is using this [HTML source](https://www.therichest.com/top-lists/top-100-richest-celebrities/)  rather than just a single line.

Comment: try this: (?<=data-srcset=\")(.*)(?= ) as your regex

Comment: That would work for that particular line but I'm scraping a webpage and it uses data-srcset for adverts aswell.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with a regular expression is going to backfire on you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)  Use a dedicated HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Change your Pattern to:

```
String regex = "<source media=\"\\(min-width: 0px\\)\" sizes=\"70px\" data-srcset=\"(.+)\"/>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

The problem is that your Current Regex has Parenthesis as part of the "text" but they are not properly escaped since they are Regular Expression operators.

Specifically

```
(min-width: 0px)
```

Should be:

```
\(min-width: 0px\)
```

And in java land since you must escape a backslash:

```
\\(min-width: 0px\\)
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "<source media=\"(min-width: 0px)\" sizes=\"70px\" data-srcset=\"https://static1.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Michael-Bloomberg.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=70&amp;h=70 70w\"/>\n";
    String regex = "<source media=\"\\(min-width: 0px\\)\" sizes=\"70px\" data-srcset=\"(.+)\"/>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

The output I get:

```
https://static1.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Michael-Bloomberg.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=70&amp;h=70 70w
```

Comment: The reason why I was using the prefix and suffix is because I am scraping a webpage and it has advert pictures that display with the data-srcset attribute.

Comment: E.g. <source media="(min-width: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-width: 1024px) and (min-resolution: 120dpi)" sizes="325px" data-srcset="https://static0.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/o-IN-N-OUT-facebook.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=325&amp;h=160&dpr=1.5 487w"/>

Comment: But I wouldn't want my code to match that

Comment: I see, That is not just your only text you are seraching

Comment: The whole text is here view-source:https://www.therichest.com/top-lists/top-100-richest-celebrities/

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately, that matches other images that aren't pictures of people. E.g. this <source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="180px" data-srcset="https://static0.therichestimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Castle_Day_MainStUSA_Right_Crowd.jpg?q=50&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=180&amp;h=120 180w"/> All pictures of people have prefix IMG_PREFIX and suffix IMG_SUFFIX. i just can't tell what my code is doing wrong

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir How can you determine an image will be of people through regex?  [See THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The images will be of people when source media="(min-width: 0px)" sizes="70px". I'm just not entirely sure how to make the code extract the link only when the prefix is matched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177231/discussion-between-raees-sharif-aamir-and-gtgaxiola).